# How to parse date time in android

Tags: android, date, datetime, time, calendar

```
**Class Utils** 
public static String getTimeAgo(String time) {

    String time_ago = "";
    try {
        // SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date past = format.parse(time);
        Date now = new Date();
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
        long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
        long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime());

        if (seconds < 60) {
            time_ago = seconds + " seconds ago";
        } else if (minutes < 60) {
            time_ago = seconds + " minutes ago";
        } else if (hours < 24) {
            time_ago = hours + " hours ago";
        } else {
            time_ago = days + " days ago";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return time_ago;
}

**Model**


public class History{
    .....
    String mTime;
    public String getTime() {
    return Utils.getTimeAgo(mTime);
}

public void setTime(String mTime) {
    this.mTime = mTime;
}
```

This is **getView** in **Adapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_history, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mTvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        holder.mTvMediaName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_mediaName);
        holder.mTvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
        holder.mImageUrl = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_url);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    final History history = mListHistory.get(position);
    holder.mTvTitle.setText(history.getTitle());
    holder.mTvMediaName.setText(history.getMediaName());
    holder.mTvTime.setText(history.getTime());
    holder.mImageUrl.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(history.getImageUrl())
        //.fit().centerInside()
        .into(holder.mImageUrl);

    return view;
}
```

I set `String time = "2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z";`

`holder.mTvTime.setText(history.getTime());` not display values

this is bug:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "43 days ago" (at offset 2)

Please. Help me!

Comment: As the error says, in `format.parse(time);`, time is a string that contains `43 days ago`, and not `2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z` as you seem to think...

Comment: Can you help me fix it ? Thanks you very much!

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you probably call `History history = ...; history.set("43 days ago");` - but you are not showing how you create the history objects so it's not possible to help you. However you should now have all the information to solve your issue.

Comment: return Utils.getTimeAgo(mTime); This retrns how many days ago, not the date. Depend on what you want dont parse it and set it as text or just return date from the method

Comment: Can you help me fix it ? Thanks you very much!

Comment: I can help you. But what do you want? mTvTime what to display date, or the time since some date?